# Removing default Claims Providers Trust - ADFS 2016

Tags: windows, active-directory, adfs

I want to know whether it is possible to remove/disable (or even hide) the default claims providers trust in the ADFS page. I have setup ADFS to point to my AzureAD so I wouldn't require the on-prem Claims providers trust anymore. Is there any way to remove it? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this via [onload.js](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/advanced-customization-of-ad-fs-sign-in-pages).

But it's a bad idea. If anything happens to Azure, how do your users authenticate with AD?

Comment: I think there is more probability of a physical AD going down rather than a PAAS provided by Microsoft